# iphone ELCImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios4

Can anyone tell me, what ELCImagePickerController is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the clone of UIImagePickerController and the mani difference between both is that with UIImagePickerController you can only select one image at a time but with ELCImagePickerController you have the provision of selecting multiple images at a time.

Comment: @user687732, @Christina, @Tariq, and anyone else that chatted here. The comment system is not a chatroom, please take this conversation to IM, a chatroom, or similar places. Thank you.